# How to defconst a bunch of stuff with the help of a macro?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I have to `defconst` 64 values in my program and given Lisp has that famous macro facility I never used as of yet, I thought this is my chance. But it does not seem to work as I expected...

```
(defun square-name (square-index)
  (multiple-value-bind (row col) (floor square-index 8)
    (format nil "SQ-~A~D"
            (string (code-char (+ (char-code #\A) col)))
            (+ 1 row))))

(defmacro defconst-all-square-names ()
  (dotimes (i 64)
    `(defconstant ,(make-symbol (square-name i)) ,i)))
    
(defconst-all-square-names)
```

Given I am relatively new to lisp and macros in particular, could someone explain,

- How I can achieve my goal of defining those constants without typing them myself.
- If I cannot use the macro, then why?

Maybe I just miss some proclaims or something like that. The code above compiles without warnings or errors and after loading it (using emacs, slime and CTRL-C-K for that), none of the constants is defined.

### UPDATE

After a little chat with @Rainer Joswig (thanks a lot!) it turns out,
that

- a macro has to *return* the code one wants to be executed
- my construct with `(make-symbol...)` did not have the desired effect and I have to use `(intern...)` instead.

With all that, the working code now looks like this:

```
(defun square-name (square-index)
  (multiple-value-bind (row col) (floor square-index 8)
    (format nil "SQ-~A~D" (string (code-char (+ (char-code #\A) col))) (+ 1 row))))

(defmacro defconst-all-square-names ()
  (append '(progn)
      (loop for i from 0 to 63 collect
           `(defconstant ,(intern (square-name i)) ,i))))
    
(defconst-all-square-names)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at `dotimes`:

```
* (dotimes (i 10) 42)
NIL
```

The `dotimes` form above returns `NIL`, the same as `()` -> the empty list. Basically it returns nothing.

So your macro returns nothing. Thus the code `(defconst-all-square-names)` expands to `()`. Check that with `macroexpand-1`.

To sum up:

- your macro has no side-effect
- your macro expands into an empty list, since your macro returns `()`

You would need to fix the latter.

Remember: the first purpose of a macro is to generate code. -> you need to generate the code, you otherwise would need to type. Since your macro does return `()` and running `()` will have naturally no effect -> nothing happens yet.

Comment: only if I write `(defmacro defconst-all-square-names ()
  (loop for i from 0 to 63 collect
    `(defconstant ,(make-symbol (square-name i)) ,i)))` it is also not working ...

Comment: @BitTickler `((foo) (foo) (foo))` is not valid code in Common Lisp. If your intention is to generate a sequence of forms, then you need to generate for example `(progn (foo) (foo) (foo))`.

Comment: (defmacro defconst-all-square-names ()
  (append '(progn)
   (loop for i from 0 to 63 collect
        `(defconstant ,(make-symbol (square-name i)) ,i)))) is not it either...

Comment: @bittickler: how do you know that? Did you use `macroexpand-1` to look at the generated code? If you look at the generated code you can see another error easily...

Comment: (macroexpand-1 'defconst-all-square-names)
DEFCONST-ALL-SQUARE-NAMES
NIL    and... SQ-A1
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNBOUND-VARIABLE SQ-A1 {10041ECA73}>.

Comment: @BitTickler: you need to macroexpand a form: `(DEFCONST-ALL-SQUARE-NAMES)`. So: `(macroexpand-1 '(defconst-all-square-names)) `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220164/discussion-between-bittickler-and-rainer-joswig).